# Can I customize which attribute controls the start of an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I'm getting this json structure back from a service

```
{
  Start: <some date>,
  End: <some date>,
  Title: 'Some Title'
}
```

fullcalendar requires me to provide lower case start, end and title, is there a way to configure it to accept the capitalized versions?

Comment: Can't you just do a string replace on "Start" to "start" ? (same for the other 2)

Comment: I could - but would rather have another solution if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/startParam/. When creating the fullcalendar instance, you can declare the startParam and endParam in the event data. I haven't tried it myself but should work fine. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That looks very promising - can't believe I missed that. Will try it out and post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have create a new object and then add each property in it.

```
var obj = {
    Start: 10,
    End: 20,
    Title: "Some Title"
};

var newObj = {};

for (var i in obj) {
    newObj[i.toLowerCase()] = obj[i];
}

console.log(newObj); // {start: 10, end: 20, title: "Some Title"}
```

Comment: Yeah - could do it that way, but that doesn't really answer the question though. I take it there is no way to configure fullcalendar to accept a random attribute as the start value. What I'm looking for is something along these lines: FullCalendar.configuration.startAttribute = 'Start';